# Firebase Test Lab for Instrumentation Lab on Flutter - "The uploaded test APK does not contain the test runner class specified in the manifest file."

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, testing, instrumentation

I am trying to use Firebase Test Lab as part of my integration testing using Flutter but I am running into this error on Firebase Console.

```
The uploaded test APK does not contain the test runner class specified in the manifest file. This is probably because the test runner isn't built into the test APK (might be in the app APK instead).
```

I followed the steps specified by the Flutter documentation @ [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#integration_test)

This is the firebase command I run on the terminal. But I also tried manually uploading the app builds to the FB TL console and get the same error.

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
--type instrumentation \
--app build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
--test build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
--timeout 3m
```